# 2 domains configured on digital ocean, only 1 works with direct browser access using Apache2

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, apache2

I have a droplet on digital ocean which was initially configured with only one domain (**andrey.dev.br**), it worked right out of the box after installing either Apache or Nginx without any extra configuration.

after some time I configured a second domain (**raphaelvieira.dev**) on the same droplet via digital ocean admin panel, the first weird behavior was that every time I tried to access the domain **raphaelvieira.dev** on the browser (chrome, firefox, etc), the browser automatically redirected it to https://raphaelvieira.dev, which is odd because I don't have a HTTPS configured on apache, but it works if I access it via terminal with curl, example:

```
curl htttp://raphaelvieira.dev
```

after some unsuccessful tries, I decided to add virtual hosts for the two domains, following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04), the first one (**andrey.dev.br**) continued to work fine via browser access or curl, but the **raphaelvieira.dev**, when accessed from browser, started to return **"www.raphaelvieira.dev took too long to respond."**, but kept working via curl on terminal.

the **raphaelviera.dev** domain is registered on google domains.

why is this happening?

Comment: i installed https on apache and now the raphaelvieira.dev is working, seems like .dev domains must have https enabled, at least for direct browser access

Comment: "why is this happening?" When you bought your `.dev` domains the registrar had the obligation to show you a message (this is required by the registry, Google) explaining that `.dev` domains requires HTTPS as the whole TLD has been added to the HSTS preloading list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue.

TLD .dev is forced to use HSTS, which means without SSL is not possible

Regarding https://get.dev/#get-started as Reference:

> Your security is our priority. The .dev top-level domain is included
> on the HSTS preload list, making HTTPS required on all connections to
> .dev websites and pages without needing individual HSTS registration
> or configuration. Security is built in.

So Enable and force SSL and also forgot any http on this as it will be useless on this kind of TLD.